# Hibernate - one-to-many

Tags: spring, hibernate, session, collections, one-to-many

Welcome,

I am using property-ref to associate this foreign key with some other column of my class rather than primary key. the column other than primary key is not unique. now when I am trying to fetch this collection I am getting exception :

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: collection is not associated with any session
```

Database :

```
T_GI_ALARM
-ALARM_ID (PK)
-METHOD_PARAM_NR (FK)

T_QC_METHOD_IN
-METHOD_IN_ID (PK)
-METHOD_PARAM_NR
```

Structure :

```
public class Alarm implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        private Integer id; 
        private Set <QCMethodIN> methodINList = new HashSet <QCMethodIN>(0);
}

public class QCMethodIN implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Integer id;
    private Integer methodNr;
```

}

Mapping:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="gestint.data.model.Alarm" 
        table="DWH1.T_GI_ALARM">
        <id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="ALARM_ID" />            
            <generator class="assigned" />            
        </id>

        <property name="qcMethode" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="METHOD_PARAM_NR" not-null="true" />
        </property>   
        <set name="methodINList" table="DWH1.T_QC_METHOD_IN" inverse="true" lazy="false" fetch="select">
            <key property-ref="qcMethode">
                <column name="METHOD_PARAM_NR" not-null="false" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="gestint.data.model.QCMethodIN" />        
        </set>

</hibernate-mapping>

<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="gestint.data.model.QCMethodIN" 
        table="DWH1.T_QC_METHOD_IN">
        <id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="METHOD_IN_ID" />            
            <generator class="assigned" />            
        </id>    
        <property name="methodNr" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="METHOD_PARAM_NR" not-null="true" />
        </property>          

    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

And I load data form hibernate (session is set by spring) like this :

```
public List<Alarm> listAll() {      
    return this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Alarm").list();
}
```

Everything work when I have a differant value for the foreigner Key, exemple :

```
T_GI_ALARM
ID  METHOD_PARAM_NR
10021   79
10022   80
10020   91

T_QC_METHOD_IN
METHOD_IN_ID    METHOD_PARAM_NR
1   79
2   80
3   91
```

But when a I have a same value for the foreigner Key (exemple with the value 79 on T_GI_ALARM) :

```
T_GI_ALARM
ID  METHOD_PARAM_NR
10021   79 <--!!
10022   80
10020   79 <--!!

T_QC_METHOD_IN
METHOD_IN_ID    METHOD_PARAM_NR
1   79 <--is call 2 times
2   80
3   91
```

I get this error :

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: collection is not associated with any session
```

I really don't understand what happen, I think is because we do not have objects with unique ID. ?!?

Answer (score 0):

You should have set **methodINList** in your QCMethodIN class because your Alarm class will have relation with QCMethodIN so it is one to many relationship between QCMethodIN and Alarm.